# Deserialize an array of Image Objects

Tags: java, android, deserialization

I have the following class:

```
public class DetailedProduct implements Serializable {
    //attributes + get and set
    private Colour colour;
    //get+set

  public class Colour implements Serializable{
     private ArrayList<Image> images;
    //get+set

    public Image[] getImages() {
      return images.toArray(new Image[images.size()]);
    }
  }

  public class Image implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3460333138445770749L;
    private String image1;
    private String image2;
    private String image3;

        //get/set methods
  }
 }
```

I created afterwards an Intent as following

```
  DetailedProduct.Colour mCurrentColour;
  Intent myIntent = new Intent(DetailsActivity.this, ImageGallery.class);
  myIntent.putExtra("Images", mCurrentColour.getImages());
  startActivity(myIntent);
```

In the ImageGallery class now I tried the following code:

```
   Serializable extras = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Images");
    if (extras != null) {
        images = (Image[]) extras;
    }
```

But I'm taking the following exception: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com./com.productdetails.ProductImageGallery}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to com.productdetails.DetailedProduct$Image[]

How can I cast correctly the serializable to an array of Image

Comment: Please, add the code for `getImages()` and link a minimal Activity

Comment: @Raffaele Please see the updates

Comment: Do you really need inner classes (ie non-static)?

Answer (score 0):

From quick thought, you can simply make the images into bytearray[], and since bite arrays primitive types which is serializable.

Answer (score 0):

You cast is not correct

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to com.productdetails.DetailedProduct$Image[]
```

You give a ListArray to intent and you try to cast it with array

this line are not correct

```
 if (extras != null) {
        images = (Image[]) extras;
    }
```

replace with

```
 if (extras != null) {
        images = (ListArray<Image>) extras;
    }
```

Comment: `Object[]` can't be cast to `Image[]`. It means it's an array of objects, not a list

Answer (score 0):

You passed the images as an arrayList. But you are taking it as an array..

Use the following code

```
Serializable extras = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Images");
    if (extras != null) {
        images = (ArrayList<Image>) extras;
    }
```

Comment: He doesn't show the implementation of `Colour.getImages()`. It can certainly return an array and not just the list member

Answer (score 0):

The Android runtime fails to serialize the array. The array type still implements `Serializable`, but when it comes back from the Bundle used by the Intent, it has lost all of its information (including type, which is always `Ljava.lang.Object`. Some answers on the internet suggest using `Parcelable`, however I tried and did not succeded myself.

What can be accomplished is transmitting a collection of `Parcelable` objects, but in the form of an `ArrayList`, which also happens to be the data structure you use in your original sample. The calling code looks like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Target.class);
ArrayList<Foo> data = new ArrayList<Foo>();
data.add(new Foo());

intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("data", data);
intent.putExtra("serializable", new Foo[] {new Foo()});
startActivity(intent);
```

I employed the usual dummy class named `Foo`, but note that implementing `Parcelable` is quite tedious. Moreover, it requires your class to have a `static` field named `CREATOR` of type `Parcelable.Creator<T>`, and with inner types this is not possible at all in the Java language. That's why you'll have to switch to nested (static) classes, eventually passing your current *outer* instance in the constructor and changing fields visibilty accordingly (from `private` to `public` or package-private). By the way, this will also improve testability of your codebase, because you reduce coupling. What I mean is, instead of this uncompilable source:

```
public class Product implements Parcelable {
  public class Color implements Parcelable {
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Color> CREATOR; // Illegal!!!
  }
}
```

something like this

```
public class Product implements Parcelable{
  public static class Color implements Parcelable {
    public Color(Product exOuter) {
    }
  }
}
```

but note that this way you won't be able to access non-static members of the enclosing class, thus it may be better to move `Color` out of `Product`.